# Binding Enums to Drop down list

Tags: c#

I have a set of Enums defined in .cs file and I wanted to bind these Enums to a drop down list  in a aspx page. I need to display that dropdown list in 4places. can someone help on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Bind Enum Types to the DropDownList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098623/how-to-bind-enum-types-to-the-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to bind dropdown with `enum`

```
drp.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum));
drp.DataBind();
```

And if you want to get the selected value

```
MyEnum empType= (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(drp.SelectedValue);
```

To Append items of 2 enum in one dropdown you can

```
drp.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum1)).Concat(Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum2)));
drp.DataBind();
```

Comment: I have 3 enums , in that I want to listout 2 in the drop down list. how can i?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do the selected binding to specific items in the list is using attributes. So create an attribute that can be applied on specific Items in the enum:

```
 public class EnumBindableAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public enum ListEnum
{
    [EnumBindable]
    Item1,
    Item2,
    [EnumBindable]
    Item3
}
```

I have specified the attribute on the Item1 and Item3, Now I can use the selected items like this ( You can generalise the following code):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> list =  this.FetchBindableList();
        this.DropDownList1.DataSource =  list;
        this.DropDownList1.DataBind();

    }

    private List<string> FetchBindableList()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = typeof(ListEnum).GetFields();
        foreach (var fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
        {
            Attribute attribute = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(EnumBindableAttribute));
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                list.Add(fieldInfo.Name);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```